# Error with SQL syntax (in Windows form , C#)

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to insert some data into my table and that's how I try to do it

```
INSERT INTO OrdersDetail 
Values (" + OrderId.Text + ", (SELECT IdProduct FROM Products WHERE ProductName = '" + listBox1.Text + "'), '" + TypeOfProductComboBox.Text + "', '" + OrderQuantity.TextAlign + "', '" + TotalCost.Text + "'");
```

and I'm geting error I think my syntax is wrong, I'm use query in query to get the product id.

The columns are :

```
OrderId (int)
ProductId(int)
ProductName(Nvarchar)
OrderQuantity(Nvarchar)
TotalCost(NvarChar)
```

Thanks

Comment: Exactly what error are you getting?

Comment: Can you please post the error

Comment: Your code is **extremely** vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. I highly recommend you switch to a safer mechanism for manipulation your database.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! Don't store `TotalCost` in a `NVARCHAR` column! It's a numeric value - so store it as a numeric value, ***PLEASE!!***

Comment: yea i know it now , didnt notice back then... thank you i will change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set your inside `SELECT` under `'`. Should be:

```
var query = "INSERT INTO OrdersDetail Values (" + OrderId.Text + ", (SELECT IdProduct FROM Products WHERE ProductName = '"+ listBox1.Text + "'), '" + TypeOfProductComboBox.Text + "', '" + OrderQuantity.TextAlign + "', '" + TotalCost.Text + "')");
```

If for example `TotalCost.Text` is a numeric data type in SQL, use

```
"..." + OrderQuantity.TextAlign + "', " + Convert.ToDouble(TotalCost.Text) + ")";
```

As p.s.w.g stated: This is open for SQL injection. Replace it with a parameterized version!

Comment: Thanks , i didnt notice i delete the ' but now i got another error that's say : 'incorrect syntex near '900' ' (900 is the total cost)

Comment: @user2120874, I guess, it is a numeric data type. Remove the `'` and cast your value to a numeric.

Comment: Hey sry for the stupid question but , how i cast the value to numeric 

and yes this is a numeric datatype

Comment: @user2120874, and don't forget the end `)` you opened for your `Values (`.

Comment: That is not a parameterized query! You should use actual `SqlParameter` objects

Comment: @Blogbeard, where on earth did I say it is? Well, my answer was mistakable I guess, I changed it.

Comment: Thanks , you helped me Alot ! also i notice to another stupid errors i did and i fix them . thank you my friend.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the first Line and your inside `Select`.

*This should work*

```
INSERT INTO OrdersDetail 
Values ('" + OrderId.Text + "',(SELECT IdProduct FROM Products WHERE ProductName ='"+ listBox1.Text + "')," + TypeOfProductComboBox.Text + "','" + OrderQuantity.TextAlign + "','" + TotalCost.Text + "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are missing the last bracket, the query should finish with `"')"` instead of `"'"` . The initial code started with opening bracket and that is why you didn't get compile errors.

But you should not create such sql queries, use [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) to avoid SQL injection attacks. You code is vulnerable to them.